# `SynchronousOnlyOperation` error while trying to run Playwright automation triggered django admin action

Tags: python, django, playwright, playwright-python

**This is the error:**

```
SynchronousOnlyOperation at /admin/app/modelA/
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

**What I'm trying to do is:**

I have an action in django-admin that intends to run an automated task with Playwright.

The action in `admin.py` looks like this:

```
@admin.action(description="Do task")
def run_task(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        task = Task(obj)
        task.run()
```

And the `Task` class looks like this:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, task: Task) -> None:
        self.task = task

    def run(self):
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
            page = browser.new_page()

            page.go_to("www.google.com")
            # DO SOME STUFF

            browser.close()
```

And when I run the action the error shows as soon as chromium gets ready.

***Thank you beforehand.***

---

I expect it to do the stuff without running at least get the title of the page.

I tried using `sync_to_async` as [these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/) suggest, implemented it in two ways (which I believe are wrong)

**First way I tried:**

Is by trying to use sync async in the `admin.py` file when the function `Task.run` is called:

```
@admin.action(description="Do task")
def run_test(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        task = Task(obj)
        sync_to_async(task.run, thread_sensitive=True)
```

*It didn't work*

**2. Second way I tried:**

Is by adding the decorator as well to the run function

```
...
    @sync_to_async
    def run(self, ...):
        ...
...
```

*It didn't work*

---

Full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/admin/app/task/

Django Version: 4.1.3
Python Version: 3.10.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'app.apps.AppConfig',
 'nested_admin']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 686, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1964, in changelist_view
    response = self.response_action(
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1593, in response_action
    response = func(self, request, queryset)
  File ".../app/admin.py", line 13, in run_test
    task.run()
  File ".../app/tasks.py", line 14, in run
    for step in self.steps:
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1866, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 87, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1396, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)

Exception Type: SynchronousOnlyOperation at /admin/app/task/
Exception Value: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Comment: Can you add whole traceback of the error you getting?

Comment: Appearantly the line `os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"`  just before running the task solves this buuuut, its unsafe for production and higher risk of file curroption as mentioned here: https://github.com/lepture/python-livereload/issues/228#issuecomment-812724362

Comment: Isn't playwright for testing only, so production safety shouldn't be concern?

Answer (score 0):

An asynchronous function can be run in django without setting DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE to True by using the @async_to_sync decorator.

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

@async_to_sync
async def async_function(...):
    await ...
```

[This documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/) might be more helpful.

Note the need to use async_playwright in the async function

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE`. Do what the error is telling you and `use a thread`. You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. You want to know when you are blocking the event loop. If your function was called by another function that was async, making your function async and calling blocking code isn't the solution.

You can use `sync_to_async` to simplify this. You do not want to use `async_to_sync` with this type of error.